# Recording 2 USB cameras using Motion

Tags: camera, motion

As stated in the title, I'm trying to record 2 USB cameras using Motion. I managed to record video in a single-camera setup; but, when I include the second camera, Motion does not record anything. I applied the procedure explained in the second answer of [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/28341/37149) question. To be more precise, I used two thread files, thread1.conf and thread2.conf, icludes this code:

```
# /usr/local/etc/thread1.conf
#
# This config file was generated by motion 3.2.12



###########################################################
# Capture device options
############################################################

# Videodevice to be used for capturing  (default /dev/video0)
# for FreeBSD default is /dev/bktr0
videodevice /dev/video0

# The video input to be used (default: 8)
# Should normally be set to 1 for video/TV cards, and 8 for USB cameras
input 8

# Draw a user defined text on the images using same options as C function strftime(3)
# Default: Not defined = no text
# Text is placed in lower left corner
text_left CAMERA 1

movie_filename %v-%Y%m%d%H%M%S-C1

############################################################
# Target Directories and filenames For Images And Films
# For the options snapshot_, jpeg_, mpeg_ and timelapse_filename
# you can use conversion specifiers
# %Y = year, %m = month, %d = date,
# %H = hour, %M = minute, %S = second,
# %v = event, %q = frame number, %t = thread (camera) number,
# %D = changed pixels, %N = noise level,
# %i and %J = width and height of motion area,
# %K and %L = X and Y coordinates of motion center
# %C = value defined by text_event
# Quotation marks round string are allowed.
############################################################

# Target base directory for pictures and films
# Recommended to use absolute patch. (Default: current working directory)
target_dir /home/pi/motion_vid

############################################################
# Live Webcam Server
############################################################

# The mini-http server listens to this port for requests (default: 0 = disabled)
webcam_port 8081

# Command to be executed when a picture (.ppm|.jpg) is saved (default: none)
# The filename of the picture is appended as an argument for the command.
on_picture_save /usr/local/motion-extras/camparse1.pl

# Command to be executed when a movie file (.mpg|.avi) is closed. (default: none)
# Filename of movie is appended as an argument for the command.
on_movie_end /usr/local/motion-extras/mpegparse1.pl
```

For the second camera, I used:

```
videodevice /dev/video1
text_left CAMERA 1
movie_filename %v-%Y%m%d%H%M%S-C2
webcam_port 8082
on_picture_save /usr/local/motion-extras/camparse2.pl
on_movie_end /usr/local/motion-extras/mpegparse2.pl
```

I tried connecting the cameras both directly to the RPi and by using a powered USB hub; and I think it's not about the power requirements.

In the main .conf file; I tried decreasing fps to 2 (to descrease the bandwidth consumption) and it didn't work either. I record the videos at 640x480 resolution.

Anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the resolution to 320 x 480. I could only get motion to stream two cameras at that resolution.